# How to create a button with a CSS-animated background?

Tags: html, css, button, css-animations

does anyone know how to create a CSS button similar to the one displayed on this page:

http://www.pennystocks.com/lp/?r=invstpd

[image: animated button]

(the white diagonal bar moves from left to right across the button, constantly)

I can see it's CSS, but I've tried searching around and not found anything really similar to this type of style.

Comment: Use your browser's dev tools to see how they do it.

Comment: They have some sort of javascript which is setting `background-position` to move background from left to right. With this background, it creates the effect http://www.pennystocks.com/lp/img/subscribe-light.png

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the website is using javascript for the animation

#### How its done

We can break this up:

- The button is given a `background-image` which in this case is a slight diagonal gradient.
- Using javascript, the position of the given `background-image` is dynamically changed using event based style changes, in other words an animation.

#### Let's do it from scratch

**Method 1** (This was the initial demo, since firefox does not support background-position-x/y it will not work, see Methods 2, 3 & 4 for that)
http://codepen.io/rajnathani/pen/qKjpL

CSS

```
button{
    margin:10px;
    padding:15px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:whitesmoke;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px grey;
    font-size:25px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position-x:-65px;

     border:2px solid skyblue;
      background-color:rgb(0,129,182);
  background-image:url('http://www.pennystocks.com/lp/img/subscribe-light.png')     
}
```

JS

```
setInterval(function(){
$('button').animate(
  {'background-position-x':'300px'},
  2000,
  function(){
    $('button').css('background-position-x','-65px')

  })}, 1800)
```

**Method 2** (creating a custom animation with setInterval)

http://codepen.io/rajnathani/pen/DyCIv

CSS

```
button{
    margin:10px;
    padding:15px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:whitesmoke;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px grey;
    font-size:25px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:-75% 0;

     border:2px solid skyblue;
      background-color:rgb(0,129,182);
  background-image:url('http://www.pennystocks.com/lp/img/subscribe-light.png')

}
```

JS

```
setInterval(function(){
  var cur_x = parseInt($('button').css('background-position').match(/^([0-9\-]+)/)[0]);
      if (cur_x <= 300){
        $("button").css('background-position', cur_x + 1 + "% 0")

      } else {
          $('button').css('background-position',"-75% 0")  
      }

    }, 1
  );
```

### An additional two methods have been added

The following methods are PURE CSS methods, there is 0kb of javascript code. That being said this method as of *today* 4th July 2013 is not 100% supported by all of the frequently used browsers. However if you are seeing this post maybe a decade later I would expect that CSS3 would have been properly implemented, and using it for the animation would be the way to go.

**Method 3** (Using CSS to produce the `background-position` animation)

http://codepen.io/rajnathani/pen/Cugol

CSS

```
@keyframes glide {
  from {
      background-position:-75% 0;
  } to {
    background-position:300% 0;

  }
}
```

And then add `animation:glide 1200ms infinite;` to the property declaration of `button`

**Method 4** (javascript feels left out, let us send HTTP to spend sometime with javascript. We'll create the gradient with css)

http://codepen.io/rajnathani/pen/FvfHk

```
button{
    margin:10px;
    padding:15px;
    font-family:verdana;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:whitesmoke;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 1px grey;
    font-size:25px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-position:-115% 0;

     border:2px solid skyblue;
      background-color:rgb(0,129,182);

    background-color:rgb(0,129,182);
    background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(
    -45deg, rgb(0,129,182),
    rgb(0,129,182) 30%,
    rgb(37,179,239) 50%, rgb(0,129,182) 70%, rgb(0,129,182) 100% 
    );
  background-image:linear-gradient(
    -45deg, rgb(0,129,182),
    rgb(0,129,182) 30%,
    rgb(37,179,239) 50%, rgb(0,129,182) 70%, rgb(0,129,182) 100% 
    );
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:135px 55px;

    -webkit-animation:glide 1050ms infinite;
  animation:glide 1050ms infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes glide {
  from {
      background-position:-115% 0;
  } to {
    background-position:225% 0;

  } 
}

@keyframes glide {
  from {
      background-position:-115% 0;
  } to {
    background-position:225% 0;

  }
}
```

Comment: thanks @CodyGuldner check the edit, added a pen which will work in firefox as well.

Comment: so cool! thank you so much. i'm going to def. take advantage of this. thanks for being so thorough... legit!!! :) :)

Answer (score 0):

This is not a pure css animate just a background-position animate using this png :
http://www.pennystocks.com/lp/img/subscribe-light.png

```
<div id="subscribelight" class="subscribe-light" style="background-position: 204px 0px;">
  <div class="subscribe-fade">
   <div class="subscribe-text" onclick="$(this).submit();">
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can do it with CSS3
http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/keyframe-animation-syntax/
or using jQuery.

I recommand you to use Firebug or Chrome Inspector (or Safari Inspector).

Answer (score 0):

It just uses this image, sets it as the the div's background and then configure it's background-position's x axis. Simple :)

Answer (score 0):

The designer has used an image to display what looks like a flash of light across the button.

[image]

They then most likely use some javascript to infinitely animate the movement of the image